# What does setAction () do for intent (Broadcast)

Tags: android, android-intent, service

What does setAction () do in intent (Service)

I don't really get what *setAction ()* does, I mostly found it in "*service to activity data passing*" example. Can the string be set freely ?. What does it do exactly ?

> When a broadcast intent is created, it must include an ACTION STRING
>   in addition    to optional data and a category string. As with
>   standard intents, data is added to
>       a broadcast intent using key-value pairs in conjunction with the putExtra() method
>       of the intent object. The optional category string may be assigned to a broadcast intent via a call to the addCategory() method.
>
> The action string, which identifies the broadcast event,  must be
>   unique and typically uses the application’s Java package name syntax. 
>   For example, the following code fragment creates and sends a broadcast
>   intent including a unique action string and data:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.Broadcast");
intent.putExtra("HighScore", 1000); sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Another variation I've seen is :

```
 Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

            broadcastIntent.setAction("com.truiton.broadcast.string");
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("Data", "Broadcast Data");
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

            try {
               Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            broadcastIntent.setAction("com.truiton.broadcast.integer");
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("Data", 10);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

            try {
               Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            broadcastIntent .setAction("com.truiton.broadcast.arraylist");
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("Data", mList);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

this looks to more like indentify the incoming data type.

Does it mean to identifies *event*, incoming *data type*, an *action* or each *Intent* creation ? Can it be set free?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction(java.lang.String)

Comment: hello RRR, I've read that I just don't get the picture yet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `<action>` tag inside `<activity>` tag to set an action in your **Manifest.xml** file is same as setting it programmatically using intent.setAction inside the java file.

These are generally used for Broadcast Receivers.

The following is an xml example:

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.SendBroadcast" >
                </action>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" >          
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

But when you want a BroadCastReceiver to register and unregister programatically then setAction() can be used.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setAction("com.example.SendBroadcast");
          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
          sendBroadcast(intent);
```

For more information just check: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers

Comment: But when you want a BroadCastReceiver to register and unregister programatically then setAction() can be used - this is just wrong 
rather `setAction()` sets the `general action to be performed`.
Example is correct just the statement following the example is wrong .