# What setAction() do for intent

Tags: java, android

what actually setAction() do? 
I found [What does setAction () do for intent (Broadcast)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260372/what-does-setaction-do-for-intent-broadcast) 
but didn't understand it clearly

```
    public void incrementWater(View view) {
        if (mToast != null) mToast.cancel();
        mToast = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.water_chug_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mToast.show();
        Intent incrementWaterCountIntent = new Intent(this, WaterReminderIntentService.class);
        incrementWaterCountIntent.setAction(ReminderTasks.ACTION_INCREMENT_WATER_COUNT);
        startService(incrementWaterCountIntent);

    }
```

Comment: Please read the docs to prevent asking similar questions. You can find it here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent . As for SetAction: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setAction(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

first you must ask yourself what do you want to do with intent!?Actions are used to describe the operation performed by the intents.Such as if the purpose of the Intent is to do a web search then the Action should be ACTION_WEB_SEARCH (It is better to do like this or you can use simple empty new Intent()). you can look at Some examples of action [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction(java.lang.String)).
in The code you sent , programmer created ACTION_INCREMENT_WATER_COUNT by himself and its type is string.[why? because of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I48y.png)